# SObject List syntax error

Tags: apex, compile-error

In Execute Anonymous, I'm trying to bulk-process a list of sObjects by passing a list to the DML operation with multiple fields.  When I just define the 'Name', it works.  When I add Field1 and Field2, I get the error below.

> Line: 4, Column: 105
>   Invalid identifier '’John’'. Apex identifiers must start with an ASCII letter (a-z or A-Z) followed by any number of ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), digits (0 - 9), '$', '_'.

```
// Define the list
List<PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c> acctList = new List<PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c>(); 
// Create PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c sObjects
PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c a1 = new PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c(Name='Account3',  Field1=’John’, Field2=’Doe’); 
PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c a2 = new PT_PIPROJ__AccountInsertTestObj__c(Name='Account4’, Field1=’Jane’, Field2=’Smith'); 
// Add accounts to the list
acctList.add(a1);
acctList.add(a2);
// Bulk insert the list
insert acctList;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the proper single quote character (`'`), whereas you have used some other single quote character (`’`).

Comment: It's a Smart Quote, probably from some Microsoft Office editor.

Comment: or slack, getting that on daily basis